# Reference field option limit for hierarchy taxonomy

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

i Create a vocabulary called Country with the following 2 terms.

England
France

and  Create a separate vocabulary and name it as City, add a new term reference called field_country so now each city term has to select a specific country term.

and  Create the following city terms.

London (field_country set to England)
Lyon (field_country set to France)
Manchester (field_country set to England)
Paris (field_country set to France)

Add the existing field_country to the Article> content type as usual.

Add a new term reference field with field name field_city and in the setting page, check the Limit this field’s options according to matching field values option as depicted in the following picture.

Now when u add a new article, the City field will get updated whenever u select a Country field.

but when
expose both the Country and City term filters. both field are show and the city does not depend on country field and if i press apply then the city field value depend on country field way ajax not work